# Apriori algorithm formula: difference between support and frequency

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, association-rules

What is the correct way to calculate support?

I have seen two different ways and I'm confused as a result. One way (say first approach) is explained https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning according to which `support = number of times an item occurs/total transactions = frequency/T` where `T` is the total number of transactions

The other approach (say second approach) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm does not divide the number of times an item occurs by the total transactions.

Consider the example given here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apriori-algorithm/, it seems that the second approach is followed. In this example the database table given below containing 9 transactions, the support for I1

[image: Database]

is 6 and not 6/9 as given below:

[image]

What is the correct approach?